# Magento 2 how to remove Category name With ID

Tags: admin, category, category-listing

here am using Magento 2.3 here category displaying category with its ID,
[image]

How to Hide or Remove these Ids. Can I get help? thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi  praveen , can you tell which  magento version you  are  using , i  checked  it  on 2.3.3 and it  only  show  product count .

Comment: Thank you @Kumar for the response, Am using Magento 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go  to

1. vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tree.php
2. comment the  code

   `// $result .= ' (ID: ' . $node->getId() . ')';`

on the line 422 at function buildNodeName($node)

```
public function buildNodeName($node)
{
    $result = $this->escapeHtml($node->getName());
    // $result .= ' (ID: ' . $node->getId() . ')';
    if ($this->_withProductCount) {
        $result .= ' (' . $node->getProductCount() . ')'; 
    }
    return $result;
}
```

That  would get your  job done .  Let me  know if  you  face any problem .

Happy Coding :)

NOTE : The right approach would  be to overwrite this function in own own module but  that would be out of scope for  this  question for  such little tweak.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought it done by configuration, no Problem ill do it by overriding that file.